# Tool for Designing Program OOP Structure

Tags: oop, visualization

Is there a tool, online or off, that will allow you to create and visualize a OOP structure so that you can plan your software before you code?

I'm looking for something that will allow me to lay out all my classes and put in method names and property names, this way I can look at the entire design at once and see what could be made better before I actually go in and write all that code.

Comment: you can use UML diagrams and there are many tools for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many tools like that, some free some very expensive. If you live in the Microsoft world Visual Studio comes with wonderful designer. Otherwise search for "UML modelling tools" on your favorite search engine...